# libarchive "not found" when Compiling Ardour on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, waf, libarchive

I'm trying to compile the stable version of [Ardour](https://www.ardour.org) (6.0.0) on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, which I've obtained via `git clone https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git`. I've managed to work out the first couple of dependancies, but am now stuck on getting past Ardour detecting **libarchive**. I also have the latest version of Homebrew (2.3.0) installed.

When I run `sudo ./waf configure --boost-include=/usr/local/boost-1.73.0/include CXX=g++-9 CC=gcc-9` to compile Ardour, this is the output:

```
Setting top to                           : /Users/kjesso/ardour/6.0.70-x86_64 
Setting out to                           : /Users/kjesso/ardour/6.0.70-x86_64/build 
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : gcc-9 
Checking for 'g++' (C++ compiler)        : g++-9 

Global Configuration 
 * Install prefix                                    : /usr/local 
 * Debuggable build                                  : True 
 * Build documentation                               : False 

Ardour Configuration 
 * Will build against private GTK dependency stack   : no 
 * Will use explicit linkage against libintl in /Users/kjesso/gtk/inst : yes 
 * Will build against private Ardour dependency stack : no 
No Carbon support available for this build

Checking for function 'dlopen' in dlfcn.h            : yes 
Checking for boost library >= 1.56                   : ok 
Checking for program 'pkg-config'                    : /usr/local/bin/pkg-config 
Checking for 'glib-2.0' >= 2.28                      : yes 
Checking for 'gthread-2.0' >= 2.2                    : yes 
Checking for 'glibmm-2.4' >= 2.32.0                  : yes 
Checking for 'sndfile' >= 1.0.18                     : yes 
Checking for 'giomm-2.4' >= 2.2                      : yes 
Checking for 'libcurl' >= 7.0.0                      : yes 
Checking for 'libarchive' >= 3.0.0                   : not found 
The configuration failed
(complete log in /Users/kjesso/ardour/6.0.70-x86_64/build/config.log)
```

Here is the output from the Ardour `build/config.log`:

```
Checking for 'libarchive' >= 3.0.0
['/usr/local/bin/pkg-config', 'libarchive >= 3.0.0', '--cflags', '--libs', 'libarchive']
err: Package libarchive was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libarchive.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libarchive' found
Package libarchive was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libarchive.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libarchive' found
```

The libarchive pkgconfig directory does contain the `libarchive.pc` file:

```
MacBookPro:ardour kjesso$ ls -al /usr/local/opt/libarchive/lib/pkgconfig
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 kjesso  staff  102  7 Jun 22:05 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 kjesso  staff  204 19 May 18:10 ..
-r--r--r--  1 kjesso  staff  378  7 Jun 22:05 libarchive.pc
```

I've already installed the latest version of libarchive 3.4.3 via homebrew, added the libarchive pkgconfig path to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable along with the other instructions from the libarchive homebrew install:

> libarchive is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
>   because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
>   parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.
>
> If you need to have libarchive first in your PATH run:
>     echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libarchive/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/kjesso/.bash_profile
>
> For compilers to find libarchive you may need to set:
>     export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libarchive/lib"
>     export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/libarchive/include"
>
> For pkg-config to find libarchive you may need to set:
>     export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libarchive/lib/pkgconfig"

Output of PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable:

```
MacBookPro:ardour kjesso$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/usr/local/opt/libarchive/lib/pkgconfig/
```

The path `/usr/local/opt/libarchive` is a symbolic link to `/usr/local/Cellar/libarchive/3.4.3/`:

```
MacBookPro:6.0.70-x86_64 kjesso$ ls -al /usr/local/opt/libarchive
lrwxr-xr-x  1 kjesso  admin  26  7 Jun 22:05 /usr/local/opt/libarchive -> ../Cellar/libarchive/3.4.3
```

I've searched online, but haven't found anything helpful. Anyone have any idea on why Ardour isn't detecting the latest version 3.4.3 of libarchive?

Comment: Probably you should just run the build command without `sudo`. It drops user-specific environment variables.

Comment: Thanks @dewaffled, that is why it was failing on libarchive. I thought I needed sudo based on something I read along the way. Now hopefully I can get past the other dependancies.

Comment: You should only need sudo to install things in system locations. And on macOS users can typically do whatever they want in `/usr/local` (otherwise `brew` would not work)